# Do I have to scale/normalize my training data for LSTM Classification, even if I only have one feature?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, lstm, data-preprocessing, feature-scaling

I have a time-series data as follows:

```
# Time, Bitrate, Class
  0.2,  312,     1
  0.3,  319      1
  0.5,  227      0
  0.6,  229      0   
  0.7,  219      0    
  0.8,  341      1    
  1.0,  401      2
```

I am using only the "Bitrate" column as a feature, and "Class" for the labels for an LSTM classification model. In case of multiple features, I need to scale my data of course, to prevent domination from one feature to another. However, in my case, do I still need to scale/normalize my data, considering there is only one feature?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still advisable to do so because your randomly initialised weights may not be able to get along with feature scale very well, and may cause the activations to saturate.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you! I have to choose the methodology (Standard Scaling/MinMax Scaling or Normalization) based on the data distribution, right?

Comment: Yes, also for neural nets, zero-mean features will probably perform better.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments!